# rails optional path scope with redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

The [Rails Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-url-params) says:

```
# config/routes.rb
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|nl/ do
  resources :books
end
```

> With this approach you will not get a **`Routing Error`** when accessing your resources such as http://localhost:3001/books without a locale. This is useful for when you want to use the default locale when one is not specified.

I would like **incorrect/missing** locales to be *redirected*... not a routing error!

For example a visit to `localhost:3000/asdf/books` should redirect to `localhost:3000/en/books`

**WHY?** because I inherited an application without any restrictions and google analytics shows a bunch of visit to a bunch of random/invalid locales. I'd prefer to keep the links working as-is for the betterment of the internet and forward them to the correct URL. Better user experience than showing a 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To redirect **incorrect** locales, add the following after the scope:

```
get '/*locale/*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}")
```

To redirect **missing** locales, change your scope from:

```
scope '(:locale)', locale: /en|nl/ do
```

to:

```
scope ':locale', locale: /en|nl/ do
```

This way the locale is no longer optional. Finally, redirect paths that are missing the locale:

```
get '/*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}"),
  constraints: lambda { |req| I18n.available_locales.none? { |locale| req.path.starts_with? locale.to_s } }
```

Final result:

```
scope ':locale', locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
  resources :books
end

get '/*locale/*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}")
get '/*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}"),
  constraints: lambda { |req| I18n.available_locales.none? { |locale| req.path.starts_with? locale.to_s } }
```